# How to include Session component in the model? CakePHP

Tags: php, cakephp, components

I really need to use `$this->Session->read('id')` in one of the model's method therefore I need to include Session component in the model. How can I do that? `public $component = array('Session');` doesn't work like in the Controller.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

the component should be and is limited to the controller.

but you can use the static access:

```
CakeSession::read('Auth.User.id')
```

etc

Answer (score 0):

For using session inside the custom component I tried with

public $components = array('Session');

and then called it by using

$this->Session->read('Auth.User.id');